# Problema al ejecutar vercel dev

Tags: json

Al querer ejecutar el comando `vercel dev` me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> C:\Users\59399\Documents\programacion\Javascript\custom-build>vercel
> dev Vercel CLI 20.1.2 dev (beta) — https://vercel.com/feedback
> > Creating initial build Running "npm run build"
>
> > @ build C:\Users\59399\Documents\programacion\Javascript\custom-build
> > rm -rf public && mkdir public && echo 'Custom Build' > ./public/index.html
>
> 'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file. npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm
> ERR! @ build: `rm -rf public && mkdir public && echo 'Custom Build' >
> ./public/index.html` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed
> at the @ build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with
> npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\59399\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-25T14_58_19_400Z-debug.log
> Error! Command "npm run build" exited with 1
> ```

¿Me pueden ayudar con esto?

Answer (score 1):

ese problema surge (o por lo menos a mí), porque el rm es un comando que no pertenece a windows, es propio de linux, por eso es que la consola no lo reconoce. Para que puedas solucionar y poder avanzar, tienes que usar un terminal que permita codigo de linux, yo en mi caso utilicé git bash, pero cualquiera que te reciba comandos de linux te servirá

Answer (score 0):

Debes instalar Vercel CLI, que permitirá usar los comandos de vercel en tu terminal Windows sin tanto lío.

Fuente: [Documentación de Vercel](https://vercel.com/blog/vercel-dev-windows)